# MongoDb - Update multiple sub directories

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am the beginner of MongoDb

Here I mentioned the document

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e5bc292361b710c7727718e"),
"branch_id" : "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91",
"inventory" : [ 
    {
        "inventory_stock_id" : "MED344",
        "stock_name" : "Anacin123",
        "stock_point" : "27",
        "stock_type" : "Medicine",
        "batch" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : 40,
                "manuf_date" : "10-01-2020",
                "exp_date" : "01-04-2020"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity" : 60,
                "manuf_date" : "15-02-2020",
                "exp_date" : "03-03-2020"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I given the values **branch_id** ="BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91" ,**inventory_stock_id** = "MED344" and **quantity** is 50

**This is my query given** but it compare the batch :[ { },{ compare this directory } ]

```
db.collection.update_many(
                                { "branch_id": "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91" },
                                { "$inc": {"inventory.$[item].batch.$[b].quantity": -50}},
                                array_filters= [
                                    {"item.inventory_stock_id": "MED344"},
                                    {"b.quantity": { "$gte": 50}}
                                ]
                                )
```

My query given Result is

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5e5bc292361b710c7727718e"),
"branch_id" : "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91",
"inventory" : [ 
    {
        "inventory_stock_id" : "MED344",
        "stock_name" : "Anacin123",
        "stock_point" : "27",
        "stock_type" : "Medicine",
        "batch" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : 40,
                "manuf_date" : "10-01-2020",
                "exp_date" : "01-04-2020"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity" : 10,
                "manuf_date" : "15-02-2020",
                "exp_date" : "03-03-2020"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected result is**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e5bc292361b710c7727718e"),
"branch_id" : "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91",
"inventory" : [ 
    {
        "inventory_stock_id" : "MED344",
        "stock_name" : "Anacin123",
        "stock_point" : "27",
        "stock_type" : "Medicine",
        "batch" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : 0,
                "manuf_date" : "10-01-2020",
                "exp_date" : "01-04-2020"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity" : 50,
                "manuf_date" : "15-02-2020",
                "exp_date" : "03-03-2020"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get my expected result anyone help me

Comment: Remove `{"b.quantity": { "$gte": 50}}` condition

Comment: @Valijon If I remove {"b.quantity": { "$gte": 50}} then this condition  { "$inc": {"inventory.$[item].batch.$[b].quantity": -50}} makes error

Comment: Try to change `$[b].quantity` to `$[].quantity` and remove condition

Comment: @Valijon If I remove {"b.quantity": { "$gte": 50}} condition then it gives quantity :-10 and quantity:10

Comment: @Valijon I faced an issue below your query produce result "cant $subtract adouble from a bool"

Comment: @Valijon  This "quantity" : {$cond:[{$lt:["$$batch.quantity", 50]}, 0, 50]} condition reduce first quantity but not subtract second quantity "batch" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : 0,
                "manuf_date" : "10-01-2020",
                "exp_date" : "01-04-2020"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity" : 50,
                "manuf_date" : "15-02-2020",
                "exp_date" : "03-03-2020"
            }
        ]

Comment: @Valijon below query batch second quantity not subtracted it shows default set 50.

Comment: Post please more samples data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use this **workaround**:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "branch_id": "BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91" },
    [{ "$set": {
        inventory: {
            $map: {
                input: "$inventory",
                as : 'inv',
                in: {
                    "inventory_stock_id" : "$$inv.inventory_stock_id",
                    "stock_name" : "$$inv.stock_name",
                    "stock_point" : "$$inv.stock_point",
                    "stock_type" : "$$inv.stock_type",
                    "batch" : {$cond:[{$ne:["$$inv.inventory_stock_id", "MED344"]}, "$$inv.batch", {
                        $map:{
                            input:"$$inv.batch",
                            as:"batch",
                            in:{
                                "quantity" : {$cond:[{$lt:["$$batch.quantity", 50]}, 0, 50]},
                                "manuf_date" : "$$batch.manuf_date",
                                "exp_date" : "$$batch.exp_date"
                            }
                        }
                    }]}
                }
            }
        }
    }}],
    {multi:true}
)
```

I am looking for easy solution than this

Comment: The above query produce "batch" : [  { "quantity" : 0.0, "manuf_date" :"10-01-2020", "exp_date" : "01-04-2020" },{ "quantity" : 10.0, "manuf_date" :"15-02-2020","exp_date" : "03-03-2020" } ]

Comment: @arunkumar check again please

Comment: batch second quantity not subtracted it default set 50

Answer (score 0):

Here mentioned using python and it will update multiple dictionary fields what I expect

```
 inventory_item_update = self.collection.find({'branch_id':"BR5cc825dac42dac3aae49ff91", "inventory.inventory_stock_id": "MED344"}) 
 quantity = 50
 update_query ={}
 if inventory_item_update:
    for cursor in inventory_item_update:
        for batch in cursor['inventory'][0]['batch']:
            if batch['quantity'] <= quantity:
               quantity = quantity-batch['quantity']
               batch['quantity'] =0
            if batch['quantity'] >= quantity:
                  quantity = batch['quantity'] -quantity
                  batch['quantity'] = quantity
         update_query = cursor
    update_result=self.collection.save(update_query)
```